# Ruby - running gem install causes missing yml file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have created my gem and I run `gem build badwordgem.gemspec` then `gem install badwordgem-0.1.0.gem` it installs it locally just fine on my machine in my :C drive

but when I check the files under
(C:\Ruby30-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\badwordgem-0.1.0)

I am missing my badlist.yml which should be located inside the lib folder.

Any idea why this is happening or any fixes for this?

**UPDATE**
Here is my files line from my gemspec.

````
spec.files = Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(__dir__)) do
    `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject do |f|
      (f == __FILE__) || f.match(%r{\A(?:(?:test|spec|features)/|\.(?:git|travis|circleci)|appveyor)})
    end
  end ```


**I've tried this now**

spec.files = Dir.glob("{bin,lib}/**/*")
````

This includes the .yml file in my lib folder when I install locally but then everything else outside of lib folder ins't there such as gemspec etc.

Comment: Probably, you forgot to include `badlist.yml` in your `.gemspec`. You need to explicitly list every file to be included using `Gem::Specification#files=`. There are various techinques to generate this list dynamically at gem-build time. What is your `files =` line?

Comment: I have updated in the question the files line @JaredBeck

Comment: Any ideas what I should have in that line or how it should be modified to not miss my badlist.yml file ? @JaredBeck

Comment: The `files =` line will be different for different gems. Instead of using the advanced `git ls-files` or `Dir.glob` techniques, how about using a simple, static array? The array should include all of your source files. It is conventional to also include the license. Some projects include a readme. For more details, read the docs on rubygems.org and look at what popular gems do.